# Relative position on Stack parent

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to build a drag&drop interface in flutter with Stack.

I've it working when the whole body is a Stack, like this.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(children: <Widget>[
      DragBox(Offset(0.0, 0.0), 'Box One', Colors.blueAccent),
      DragBox(Offset(200.0, 0.0), 'Box Two', Colors.orange),
      DragBox(Offset(300.0, 0.0), 'Box Three', Colors.lightGreen),

  ]);
)
```

The drop method in the DragBox is like this

```
  onDraggableCanceled: (velocity, offset) {
    setState(() {
      position = offset;
    });
  },
```

But when I've a Scaffold and the Stack is just the body, coordinates don't work ok.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: _buildAppBar(),
    body: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        DragBox(Offset(0.0, 0.0), 'Box One', Colors.blueAccent),
        DragBox(Offset(200.0, 0.0), 'Box Two', Colors.orange),
        DragBox(Offset(300.0, 0.0), 'Box Three', Colors.lightGreen),
      ],
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: _buildBottomNavbar(),
  );
)
```

As you can see in the img, it has an error due to the bar I think.

[image: drag_drop]
I've also tried with this drop method but it does not use the stack to convert coordinates to local, I think.

```
onDraggableCanceled: (velocity, offset) {
  setState(() {
          RenderBox rb = context.findRenderObject();
          Offset off2 = rb.globalToLocal(offset);
          position = off2;
        });
      },
```

Thanks

Comment: Unclear. Can you add more details about the problem and the desired result ?

Comment: added. Sorry for not being clear from the begining

Answer (score 0):

At the end I solved it using a GestureDetector in the child and moving relative to the gesture start position, like this:

```
Positioned(
    left: 0.0,
    top: 0.0,
    child: GestureDetector(
        onScaleStart: (details) {
          //Store start conditions
          _startPos = details.focalPoint;
        },
        onScaleUpdate: (scaleDetails) {
          setState(() {
            position += scaleDetails.focalPoint - _startPos;
            _startPos = scaleDetails.focalPoint;
          });
        },
        ....
```